# change new date format

Tags: javascript, date, date-format

I am trying to get today's date with some specific format:

```
var d = new Date();
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var curr_Month = d.getMonth();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var todayDate =   (curr_year +"/"+curr_Month +"/"+ curr_date );
```

This is not working. What is the proper way of changing my date's format?

Comment: Seems to be working fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/adT8j/

Comment: month is showing as 10 , but its 11 ...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: Months are 0 based in javascript, ie January is month 0

Comment: I love js, but always I have to admit this is easily one of the least intuitive parts of the entire language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, the months are zero based. For example:

> January = 0
>
> February = 1
>
> ...

Simply add one to your month:

```
var d = new Date();
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var curr_Month = d.getMonth() + 1; // +1 to zero based month
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var todayDate =   (curr_year +"/"+curr_Month+"/"+ curr_date );
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adT8j/1/).

Comment: Adding +1 solved the problem , but i am surprised if my system date is less than november it works fine , but if my system date is november or december it doesnt work..

Answer (score 3):

```
var curr_Month = d.getMonth() + 1; //months are zero based
```